# PartialView rendered as new page instead of being rendered on main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm triying to create a set of cascading dropdown lists, my main view consists of a set of two partial views:

```
@model  WebUI.Controllers.IndexViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>Category </td>
    <td> :</td>
    <td>@Html.Partial("ParentsUserControl", Model)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sub - Category </td>
    <td> :</td>
    <td><div id="Children">@Html.Partial("ParentChildrenUserControl", Model)</div></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Each partial view has a AJAX form with a dropdown:

```
@model WebUI.Controllers.IndexViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectParent", "Ticket", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Children" }))
{ 
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.SelectedParenId,
        new SelectList(Model.AvailableParents, "EstablishmentId", "Name"),
       string.Empty
    )
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#SelectedParenId').change(function () {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
</script>
```

The problem is that as soon as I click on an item of the first list, a new page is rendered with the second partial view, **how can I make it render the partial view inside of the main view and not generate a new page?, what does the UpdateTargetId refer to?**

and **Also how can I send the values selected by the user back to the controller? all Im creating is  a table, should i put that table inside a form?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if in web.cnfig file the following key is added or not

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes. I had this same problem and you have provided the solution. He needs to also make sure he is including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in his scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes If you put the table inside the form the framework will automatically store all your model values inside a model wrapper. This is called Model Binding and you can use it directly in your controller action.